# Get invoice that has sales order and invoice without Sales Order

Tags: sql-server-2008, sapb1

I want to achieve the following query. 
What i want here is to compare the Invoice Amount from the Sales so the fields that i'll be needing are these:

```
OSLP.SalesPerson|OINV.CardName|OINV.DocDate|OINV.DocNum|OINV.DocTotal|ORDR.DocDate|ORDR.DocTotal|OINV.GrosProfit
```

What i have done so far is this,

```
Declare  @mindate date = '10.01.16', @maxdate date = '10.31.16'
SELECT DISTINCT
T6.SlpName [Sales Person],  
T5.CardName [Customer Name],
T5.DocDate [TRA Date],
T5.DocNum [TRA No],
T5.DocTotal [TRA Total],
(SELECT SUM(T8.DocTotal) FROM ORIN T8 INNER JOIN RIN1 T9 ON T8.DocEntry=T9.DocEntry WHERE T8.DocDate BETWEEN @mindate AND @maxdate) [Credit Amnt],
T1.DocDate [SO Date],
T1.DocTotal [SO Total],
T5.GrosProfit [Gross Profit]
FROM RDR1 T0  
INNER JOIN ORDR T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry  
left outer JOIN DLN1 T2 on T2.BaseEntry = T0.DocEntry  
left outer JOIN ODLN T3 on T2.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry  
left Outer JOIN INV1 T4 on T4.BaseEntry = T3.DocEntry AND T4.BaseLine = T2.Linenum AND T4.BaseType = 15
       OR (T4.Basetype=17 and T4.BaseEntry=T0.DocEntry AND T4.BaseLine=T0.LineNum)  
left outer JOIN OINV T5 on T5.DocEntry = T4.DocEntry  
left outer JOIN OSLP T6 on T6.SlpCode = T1.SlpCode
WHERE T5.DocDate BETWEEN @mindate AND @maxdate
Group by 
T6.SlpName, T5.CardName, T1.CardCode,
T5.DocDate, T5.DocNum,  T5.DocTotal,
T1.DocDate, T1.DocTotal,  T5.GrosProfit
ORDER BY 
T5.CardName, T5.DocDate
```

As you can i see, i included the ORIN(Credit Memo) table to deduct the SUM of OINV.DocTotal with ORIN.DocTotal.

So, this query works as it's suppose to be BUT, I am not able to get those invoices that has no related documents like Sales order or Delivery. Solely, it's just invoice.

Comment: I think your join to DLN1 needs to join on BaseLine as well as BaseEntry. You'll get duplicate results for multi-line delivery notes as it is.

Comment: I think you'll need to UNION in another query where you select only invoices that have no link to a base document (i.e. RDR1.BaseEntry is zero) then take the aggregate of both queries. Remember however that links between documents are quite flexible, you can go from Order to Delivery to Invoice, or straight from Order to Invoice. To cover all bases you would probably need three queries in your union.